# Twitter API: Obtain retweets _of_ a non-authenticated user

Tags: api, twitter

Is there a way to obtain all retweets *of* a specific user?

Something of the form "statuses/retweets_of_user" (statuses/retweets_of_me exists, but only works for the authenticated user).

This ticket comes close, but has been marked as a duplicate of another ticket that is now closed.

http://code.google.com/p/twitter-api/issues/detail?id=1276

That other ticket introduces a "include_rts" parameter to the user_timeline API. However, I am not interested in retweets *to* a specific user, I want retweets *of* a specific user.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use the [GET statuses/retweeted_by_user](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/retweeted_by_user) endpoint.